# How to debug this my Class in php

Tags: php, class

MyDocumentRoot/MyClasses/LoginStatus.php is as follows

```
<?php
    Class Hos_LoginStatus
    {
        protected $_signedInUser;
        public function setUserSignedIn()
        {
            session_start();
            if (isset($_SESSION['userSignedIn']))
                $this->_signedInUser = $_SESSION['userSignedIn'];
            elseif (isset($_SESSION['emailSigedIn']))
                $this->_signedInUser = $_SESSION['emailSignedIn'];
            else
                $this->_signedInUser = "";
        }
        public function getUserSignedIn()
        {
            return $this->_signedInUser;
        }
    }
```

The relevant part of MyDocumentRoot/index.php is as follows

```
<?php
   require_once 'MyClasses/LoginStatus.php';
   $myLogIn = new Hos_LoginStatus();
   $signedInName->getUserSignedIn();
   echo $signedInName;
?>
```

Please debug the above; I am new in using classes.

Comment: What do you mean by debug? what's the error?

Comment: Please debug the above is very unclear. Debugging is something you should've done before you post your question and then when it's still unclear or your stuck. You post your specific question about the issue.

Comment: `"Please debug the above"` - Stack Overflow is not a crowd-sourced debugging tool.  *You* debug it, and *you* explain the problem you're finding.  We can help with that problem.  "Something is wrong, find the problem and fix it for me" is not a valid question.

Comment: The code is not working. I am unable to fix the error in this. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only problem I see is the way youre accessing your method:

```
$myLogIn = new Hos_LoginStatus();
$signedInName->getUserSignedIn();
```

`$signedInName` is not defined anywhere, it should be:

```
$myLogIn = new Hos_LoginStatus();
$signedInName = $myLogIn->getUserSignedIn();
```

You should probably turn `error_reporting` on in order to see encountered errors.

Comment: Thank You CodeGodie; I have edited as below from your input.
`<?php
Class Hos_LoginStatus
{
protected $_signedInUser;
public function getUserSignedIn()
{
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['userSignedIn']))
 $this->_signedInUser = $_SESSION['userSignedIn'];
elseif (isset($_SESSION['emailSigedIn']))
 $this->_signedInUser = $_SESSION['emailSignedIn'];
else
 $this->_signedInUser = "";
return $this->_signedInUser;
}
}
`
`
<?php
require_once 'MyClasses/LoginStatus.php';
$myLogIn = new Hos_LoginStatus();
$signedInName = $myLogIn->getUserSignedIn();
echo $signedInName;
?>
`
Now it works fine